# Windows image processing question

Tags: windows, image-processing

absolute newbie in this space so please adjust :-)

this has to work on windows ( C++ or .net ok )

The problem is I have a set of images ( for illustration say a deck of cards )

Given a sub image like say an Ace or 5 diamonds or whatever I need to find all the images from the original set that contain the new image. Its pretty analogous to a sub string problem except that you cannot do a binary comparison as the sub-image might be oriented a little differently or be off by a bit  so that binary comparisons will fail but just looking at the image it is very obvious that a match exists. This is 2-D image issue only not like facial recognition where the degrees of freedom so to speak are way too many.

I am looking for 3rd party libs that may have solved this problem

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is recommended for such sort of analysis.

See [object detection](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_object_detection.html) section.